# taking time difference from time in different format in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data.table dt which have many records .

It have two columns datetime1, with value as "2017-04-19 09:54:00" of class `POSIXct`

another column have time values like "7.97" of class `numeric`. It is for the same date.

I want to calculate a difference in the time in minutes. how can I do it in R

Comment: it is hours. The digit before the decimal is the hours and digits after decimal are minutes in hundred parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functions of `lubridate` to extract `hour`, `minute`, and `second` of the `POSIXct` and then calculate the difference.

```
library(lubridate)
x = as.POSIXct("2017-04-19 09:54:00", tz = "UTC")
hour(x) * 60 + minute(x) + second(x)/60 - 7.97 * 60
#[1] 115.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
time1 <- as.POSIXct('2017-04-19 09:54:00')
time2 <- as.POSIXct('2017-04-19 00:00:00') + 3600*7.97
60*as.numeric(time1 - time2)
```